# List Structures

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I am interested to create a list like the below one, which starts with `\noindent` but then is pushing the text to the left **but without the text in the item returning again to `\noindent` when there is a newline** (see the picture). I couldn't achieve the desired results.

[image]

Comment: 'tried [a] few things': please can we see what they were? Am I right in understanding that you want a hanging indent for your list?

Answer (score 3):

Something like that? It was made using convenient options from the `enumitem` package, that may be set globally in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = Test~\arabic*.,wide = 0pt, leftmargin = 1.5em]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]